# STM32cubeIDE doesnt find the necessary .elf file when runnning or debugging the program

Tags: stm32cubeide

Disclaimer: I'm new to stm32CubeIDE or essentially anything related to it and have practicly no clue what I'm doing. I study Mechanical Engineering and to install a sensor I'm unfortunately obligated to work outside my area of expertise.
I'm using it tho, together with arduino IDE, to read and calibrate a Hall Effect Sensor. I got the program from one of my teammembers and it's functional on his computer. When I try to run the program it shows the following:

[Error Notification](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2v6zO.png)

now I tried locating the missing file, but it's nowhere in the files that where send to me.

1. I did a bit of research and apparently cubeide might generate the file on its own upon (re)building the program. I tried rebuilding but It gave the same error.
2. My teammember had a look at it and mentioned it tries to locate/open specific files twice after he had a look over the following debugreport (it's rather long, but I don't know what's relevant so here's all of it):

***13:14:22 **** Incremental Build of configuration Debug for project Solarboat Sensor Hub ****
make -j12 all
arm-none-eabi-gcc -o "Solarboat Sensor Hub.elf" @"objects.list"   -mcpu=cortex-m4 -T"C:\Users\lenwi\Downloads\han solarboat\TestAngleOfAttack\STM32L432KCUX_FLASH.ld" --specs=nosys.specs -Wl,-Map="Solarboat Sensor Hub.map" -Wl,--gc-sections -static --specs=nano.specs -mfpu=fpv4-sp-d16 -mfloat-abi=hard -mthumb -u _printf_float -u _scanf_float -Wl,--start-group -lc -lm -Wl,--end-group

c:\st\stm32cubeide_1.12.0\stm32cubeide\plugins\com.st.stm32cube.ide.mcu.externaltools.gnu-tools-for-stm32.10.3-2021.10.win32_1.0.200.202301161003\tools\arm-none-eabi\bin\ld.exe: ./Core/Src/main.o:C:/Users/lenwi/Downloads/han solarboat/TestAngleOfAttack/Debug/../Core/Inc/data_processor.h:19: multiple definition of `adc_buf'; ./Core/Src/data_processor.o:C:/Users/lenwi/Downloads/han solarboat/TestAngleOfAttack/Debug/../Core/Inc/data_processor.h:19: first defined here

c:\st\stm32cubeide_1.12.0\stm32cubeide\plugins\com.st.stm32cube.ide.mcu.externaltools.gnu-tools-for-stm32.10.3-2021.10.win32_1.0.200.202301161003\tools\arm-none-eabi\bin\ld.exe: ./Core/Src/main.o:C:/Users/lenwi/Downloads/han solarboat/TestAngleOfAttack/Debug/../Core/Inc/data_processor.h:20: multiple definition of `Hall_LUT_array'; ./Core/Src/data_processor.o:C:/Users/lenwi/Downloads/han solarboat/TestAngleOfAttack/Debug/../Core/Inc/data_processor.h:20: first defined here

c:\st\stm32cubeide_1.12.0\stm32cubeide\plugins\com.st.stm32cube.ide.mcu.externaltools.gnu-tools-for-stm32.10.3-2021.10.win32_1.0.200.202301161003\tools\arm-none-eabi\bin\ld.exe: ./Core/Src/main.o:C:/Users/lenwi/Downloads/han solarboat/TestAngleOfAttack/Debug/../Core/Inc/data_processor.h:21: multiple definition of `CANtxData'; ./Core/Src/data_processor.o:C:/Users/lenwi/Downloads/han solarboat/TestAngleOfAttack/Debug/../Core/Inc/data_processor.h:21: first defined here

c:\st\stm32cubeide_1.12.0\stm32cubeide\plugins\com.st.stm32cube.ide.mcu.externaltools.gnu-tools-for-stm32.10.3-2021.10.win32_1.0.200.202301161003\tools\arm-none-eabi\bin\ld.exe: ./Core/Src/main.o:C:/Users/lenwi/Downloads/han solarboat/TestAngleOfAttack/Debug/../Core/Inc/data_processor.h:22: multiple definition of `mailbox_number'; ./Core/Src/data_processor.o:C:/Users/lenwi/Downloads/han solarboat/TestAngleOfAttack/Debug/../Core/Inc/data_processor.h:22: first defined here

c:\st\stm32cubeide_1.12.0\stm32cubeide\plugins\com.st.stm32cube.ide.mcu.externaltools.gnu-tools-for-stm32.10.3-2021.10.win32_1.0.200.202301161003\tools\arm-none-eabi\bin\ld.exe: ./Core/Src/main.o:C:/Users/lenwi/Downloads/han solarboat/TestAngleOfAttack/Debug/../Core/Inc/data_processor.h:23: multiple definition of `MPU9250_data'; ./Core/Src/data_processor.o:C:/Users/lenwi/Downloads/han solarboat/TestAngleOfAttack/Debug/../Core/Inc/data_processor.h:23: first defined here

c:\st\stm32cubeide_1.12.0\stm32cubeide\plugins\com.st.stm32cube.ide.mcu.externaltools.gnu-tools-for-stm32.10.3-2021.10.win32_1.0.200.202301161003\tools\arm-none-eabi\bin\ld.exe: ./Core/Src/main.o:C:/Users/lenwi/Downloads/han solarboat/TestAngleOfAttack/Debug/../Core/Inc/data_processor.h:24: multiple definition of `status'; ./Core/Src/data_processor.o:C:/Users/lenwi/Downloads/han solarboat/TestAngleOfAttack/Debug/../Core/Inc/data_processor.h:24: first defined here

collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [makefile:64: Solarboat Sensor Hub.elf] Error 1
"make -j12 all" terminated with exit code 2. Build might be incomplete.

13:14:23 Build Failed. 7 errors, 0 warnings. (took 1s.187ms)***

3. He ended up "cleaning"? the code/file, made no difference.
4. He then run an update which according to him should've fixed it. still nothing.
5. we tried running it on someone elses device but it still didnt work.
6. This made me to suspect it might have been the files he send me. We checked them and apart from the .elf file that was missing it was all there.

I tried doing more research but with lack of background knowlegde I don't exactly know what to look for and my teammate unfortunately doesn't have time.

upon request I can of course send more details, but I wouldnt know what to be relevant and what not so I did not include it here.